# Let $G$ be a group of order $34$ and $H$, a subgroup of $G$ not normal in $G$. Then $H$ has order $2$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group of order $34$ and $H$, a subgroup of $G$ not normal in $G$. Then $H$ has order $2$.

I forgot how to do this type of problem. I know it has to do with the number of classes.

If $H$ not normal then exists $g\in G$ such that $gH=Hg.$ Also

$$G=\bigcup_{g\in G}gH$$

At what point should I use that the group has order $34$? I just ask for a hint

Comment: If it didn't have order $2$, what could its order be?

Comment: 1 or 17... by _Lagrange theorem

Comment: (or 34).  But the ones of order 1 and 34 must be normal, so they're out.  What about the ones of order 17?

Comment: thanks! If $|H|=1$ then $H=\left\{e\right\}$ then $H$ normal a contradiction.
If $|H|=17$ then $[G:H]=2$ then H normal in $G$

Comment: oh yes, |H|=34 then H=G normal a contradiction

Comment: A [very similar Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884475/proving-that-a-subgroup-is-not-normal) earlier dealt with a non-abelian group of order $6$. Mutatis mutandi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $|H|\neq 2$ then $|H|\in\left\{1,17,34\right\}$

If $|H|=1$ or $|H|=34$ then $H$ normal a contradiction.

If $|H|=17$, $[G:H]=2$ then $H$ normal, a contradiction.

Therefore $|H|=2.$

Comment: You didn't really prove this by contradiction.  You proved the contrapositive.